# How can I using OpCodes and Emit set a parameter to an instantiated Property of type T?

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates, opcode

I am trying to write a Method that returns that a DynamicMethod which when Invoked sets the first parameter to an object of Type T, This Object is called Value and is set when the class is instantiated, This is the code i've got right now:

```
using HarmonyLib;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public class OriginalCode<T>
{
public delegate void PostFix(ref T __result);
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public OriginalCode(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public MethodInfo Postfix()
    {
        var result = new DynamicMethod("NewPostfix", typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(T).MakeByRefType() }, typeof(Program).Module);
        result.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "__result");
        
        ILGenerator il = result.GetILGenerator();
        
        Type type = typeof(OriginalCode<T>);
        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty("Value");

        // create a reference to the Value Property
        PropertyInfo ValueProperty = typeof(OriginalCode<T>).GetProperty("Value");

        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, Value);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stind_Ref);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
        return result;
    }
}
```

so this is how I would use it:

```
string testRefStr = "Test";
var originalCodeInstance = new OriginalCode<string>("New Test");
var newStringDelegate = (OriginalCode<string>.PostFix)originalCodeInstance.Postfix().CreateDelegate(typeof(OriginalCode<string>.PostFix));
newStringDelegate(ref testRefStr);

int testRefInt = 55;
var originalCodeInstance = new OriginalCode<int>(75);
var newIntDelegate = (OriginalCode<int>.PostFix)originalCodeInstance.Postfix().CreateDelegate(typeof(OriginalCode<int>.PostFix));
newIntDelegate(ref testRefInt);
```

this currently only works if T is a string, but I need it to work on all types incuding reference and primitive types and Tasks/Interfaces and other abstract types.

How would i go about implementing this? im not very good at Opcodes and IL its outside of my knowledge - im really only working with it for this part, im so close but I'm quite stuck.
Thanks All

I know the reason for the failiure with other types is that `Opcodes.Ldstr` only loads a string - I have also tried `OpCodes.Ldobj` but it didn't work for me - since i can't debug OpCodes in a DynamicMethod i always get unhelpful outputs such as `Invalid Code detected`.

I have attempted using `OpCodes.Callvirt` but that also didn't work for a similar reason to above

I have tried to get the method definition of the Getter of the `Value` property and trying to use `Opcodes.Call` - this didn't work either.

If you think these Opcodes should work please remember im not familiar with Opcodes and more-than-likely didn't properly use it haha - please tell me how to properly use the Opcodes.

Thanks All

Comment: with the edit: `new object[] {ref testRefString}` - um, nope; that's not a thing you can do

Comment: Rather than showing what you're currently doing, which is doomed: can you please *very clearly* state just what you're *trying to achieve*. Something may be possible, but it will most likely require a custom delegate type, for example `delegate void Foo<T>(ref T value)` and creating a `Foo<int>` in this case that you can then `Invoke(ref testRefStr)`

Comment: It also isn't clear what the significance of `OriginalCode` and `MethodBase` are here; I'm very knowledgeable about ref-emit, but I can't infer what you're trying to do here... for example, why is this not just: `public void Apply(ref T value) => value = Value;` ? what are you trying to do that is more complicated than that?

Comment: or if you absolutely want it as a delegate rather than a method: `public delegate void NamingIsHard(ref T value); public NamingIsHard Postfix() => (ref T arg) => arg = Value;`

Comment: Im using Harmony to Patch a method at runtime, and i want to use a method that takes the value of this instantiated class and generate the method that patches it - usually you have to use a static method only, i want it to be non static

Comment: OK, I can try and answer the opcode question, but seriously: why are you even using ref-emit here? isn't this literally just `public PostFix Postfix() => (ref T arg) => arg = Value;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion, it seems that the underlying requirement here is to set an arg to an arbitrary value, from (for some reason) a delegate to a static method. Now, the problem here is that the types you can write *directly* in IL are very limited - integers, strings, floating-point, nulls, etc. If you only need to work with a few very specific types, then you can special-case each, but in the general case: that just doesn't work. As such, the typical workaround is to use ref-emit to declare a dynamic *type*, with a static field where we can shove the value, and then essentially use (as our method body):

```
larg {the arg}
ldsfld {the field with the value we want}
stobj {the type of the field}
ret
```

This requires a lot more work than `DynamicMethod`, as you need an `AssemblyBuilder`, `ModuleBuilder`, `TypeBuilder` and `MethodBuilder` etc. But: it should work:

```cs
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Reflection;

int testRefInt = 55;
var theMethod = new OriginalCode<int>(75).Postfix();
// test the method
var callable = theMethod.CreateDelegate<PostFix<int>>();
callable(ref testRefInt);
Console.WriteLine(testRefInt); // 75

public delegate void PostFix<T>(ref T __result);

public class OriginalCode<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public OriginalCode(T value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }

    public MethodInfo Postfix()
    {
        var ab = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("foo"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndCollect);
        var mb = ab.DefineDynamicModule("foo");
        var tb = mb.DefineType("bar", TypeAttributes.Public);
        // define a field (important: do not mark it as readonly)
        var fb = tb.DefineField("theField", typeof(T), FieldAttributes.Static);
        // define the method
        var method = tb.DefineMethod("theMethod", MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.Public,
            typeof(void), new Type[] { typeof(T).MakeByRefType() });
        var il = method.GetILGenerator();
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldsfld, fb);
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Stobj, typeof(T));
        il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        // create the actual type and set the value of the static field
        var type = tb.CreateType();
        type.GetField("theField", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static).SetValue(null, Value);

        // get the method that does the swap
        return type.GetMethod("theMethod", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, could you direct me to some documentation please, This is very new to me but im willing to learn. Where in the method would i need an `AssemblyBuilder` and the other Objects? and how would i go implementing them? Thanks Marc

Comment: @NannerBannaner23 I'm working on a full example, give me a few moments

Comment: @NannerBannaner23 it *should* be something like this, but... this isn't working yet; need to step away from PC, but will try to take another peek later: (removed broken link)

Comment: ah! probably needs ldarg, not ldarga

Comment: @NannerBannaner23 fixed it ^^^

Comment: Thanks man, ill try this out, im sure it will work and ill let you know. Thanks bro

Comment: @NannerBannaner23 note that if you're creating multiple, you'll either need to keep the assembly builder and keep using it to add extra types, or you'll need a different assembly-name each time (maybe just a counter/increment)

Comment: That worked, you absolute Legend, setting this as Answered. Thanks man. Ill check out you Blog as well - I want to be as smart as you one day haha

Comment: I See, ill keep the Assembly Builder thing in mind, ill most likely be making multiple requests to this method so some update would be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what you want to *achieve*:

```
int testRefInt = 55;
new OriginalCode<int>(75).Postfix().invoke(OriginalCode, new object[] {testRefInt})

//testRefString should now be "NewString" and testRefInt should now be 75
```

What you are asking for **is not possible**. The expression `new object[] {testRefInt}` *does not take the reference of `testRefInt`*; it copies the *current value* of `testRefInt` (55) onto the stack, "boxes" that, then passes the reference to the newly constructed box into an array. Regardless of what your code does **it cannot impact `testRefInt`**. That is not a thing you can do.

To do *that*, you would need to pass `ref testRefInt` somewhere, but you cannot "box" a `ref` (`ref` values are only valid in locals, on the stack, or as fields on `ref struct` values, which *also* are only valid in locals, on the stack, or as fields on other `ref struct` values).

Comment: sorry when i was writing the question i was indeed writing some Pseudocode, my bad - I have been using ref when passing it in, forgot to add to question sorry, I've now updated to reflect that

Comment: @NannerBannaner23 ok, but the specifics **really really really matter here**. If you can't show the exact scenario (even if it is just a simplified standalone copy of your code that we can at least compile and hopefully run, even if it doesn't work): *we won't be able to help you*

Comment: This should run now, I just ran it with a string.

Comment: @NannerBannaner23 what should? I'm 100% certain that `new object[] {ref testRefString});` did not compile

Comment: Sorry you're right, ive just updated it with a `CreateDelegate` which worked - was just a bit too triggerhappy when i wrote it.